# Electron Forge doesn't package EXE with my custom ICO

Tags: electron-packager, electron-forge

I'm trying to compile my application to EXE with a custom icon using forge.

This is my **force.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
      icon: './ico'
  }
};
```

ico.ico file is located in the main app folder. The ico is a 256x256px image.

The package command is:

```
electron-forge package --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

But the generated electron EXE still has the default electron icon.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was windows Icon cache!

```
ie4uinit.exe -show
```

and restart explorer.exe